# How long does a GC take?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, clr

We have a theory that gen 2 GCs could be introducing delays into an application, is there a way to profile how long GCs take?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288898/how-to-profile-net-garbage-collector.

Answer (score 5):

There are performance counters for the total time spent in GC and various info about number of collections, heap sizes and so on. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163528.aspx#S2) for detailed instructions.

If you just want a quick look at an application, use the [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653). It can show most of the .NET statistics for a process.

Comment: I'm looking specifically for how long a single full GC takes.  Is it suspending everything for 10 ms... 100 ms... 500 ms.

Answer (score 3):

The .NET 4.0 has ETW for GC which can help in profiling the time spent on GC.

Here is an answer similar to your question [Can you repro this 64-bit .NET 4 GC bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967176/can-you-repro-this-64-bit-net-4-gc-bug/3988524#3988524)

Answer (score 0):

Perfview tracks all sorts of useful information about GC:

Downlaod:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567

Blog post + Video:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/10/09/improving-your-app-s-performance-with-perfview.aspx